# How does html recognize the html tags inside a piece of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to JS and seem to encounter an uncommon case here.

**Problem:**
I am modifying a piece of code using the react framework., In the render() function I see that the code is putting all the s with different classnames to render the different components. What I want to accomplish is getting an array (of strings) from props and render each string with a line break. For example:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div classname=classA>
      {this.props.arrayA}
    </div>
  );
}
```

where arrayA would be something like ['abc','bcd','cde'].

**My Attempt**:
I looked up a couple answers related to how to recognize the html tags inside the js code. They suggested using DOM or something like document.write(). In my case I am directly writing inside a DOM element already, so I just want to use a for loop to achieve this:

```
arrayA[0]
<br>
arrayA[1]
<br>
arrayA[2].
```

I thought I can do something like arrayA.join(br). However, I cannot find a way so that the "br" would be recognized as a line break as HTML tags. I even read some comments saying it's dangerous to insert HTML tags inside js code due to XSS attack. Please advise what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: The tags are not HTML tags, they are JSX. JSX is syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`. It is all JavaScript.

Comment: It doesn't.  The JSX compiler is converting those HTML blobs into react.createElement calls.

Comment: If you're using React framework for your project then having to use `document.write` (or DOM API in general) is a red flag that you're probably not using the framework properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning:** Direct DOM manipulations are a serious react anti-pattern.

The normal pattern for rendering arrays of elements is to `map` them, but you want to insert a break between each, so you have what amounts to a [fencepost problem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fencepost_problem)

```
render() {
  return(
    <div classname=classA>
      {this.props.arrayA.map((el, index) => {
        return index ? (
          // render break and element if not first index
          <Fragment>
            <br />
            <div>{el}</div>
          </Fragment>
        ) : (
          // render element if first index
          <div>{el}</div>
        ) 
      }}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
const data = ['abc','bcd','cde'];

const App = ({ data }) => {
  return <div>{data.map((el, i) => {
    return i ? (
      <React.Fragment key={i}>
        <br />
        <div>{el}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    ) : (
      <div key={i}>{el}</div>
    )
  })}</div>
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

**FYI** `<div>`'s are already block level elements so the breaks may not be necessary, and you can just do a plain mapping, i.e. `this.props.arrayA.map(el => <div>{el}</div>)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think your FYI can really just solve my problem. I didn't know it's a block level element

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the "React" way to do this would be to create a component that you can feed your array of strings into, which handles the display as you require.  Something like

```
const Row = ({ value }) => (
  <div>
    {value}
  </div>
);
```

And then you can use that like

```
render() {
  return(
    <div classname=classA>
      {this.props.arrayA.map(val => <Row value={val} key={val} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```